# Find word starting with $ from given string with angular 2

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I want to find word starting with $.

```
var s = "$hello, this is a $test $john #doe";
var re = /(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g, match, matches = [];
while (match = re.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

Above regex gives me word starting with #, But I can't use same regex for finding word starting with $.

So How can i find word starting with $ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this regex,

```
 var str = "$iPhone should be ab#le to complete and $delete items";
    alert(str.match(/(^|\s)\$(\w+)/g).map(function(v){return v.trim().substring(1);}));
    });
```